java - postgress authentication failing even though host,port,username,password are correct
I'm a .NET dev trying to learn java. I have a postgres instance running at localhost:5432 using docker, with database "knowledgemap", username "knowledgemap" and password "test123". I'm able to connect to this postgres instance using a .NET application and do all operations correctly. But when I'm try to connect to it using my java application, it's breaking with the error message FATAL: password authentication failed for user "knowledgemap". I'm using a windows 11 laptop. I checked the firewall settings and allowed java and IntellijIDEA to use public and private networks, but still getting the error. Please give any advice where to start debugging this issue.
Java code:
package org.example;
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/knowledgemap";
        String username = "knowledgemap";
        String password = "test123";
        Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Java_PostgresConnectionTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

EDIT:
Postgres version: PostgreSQL 16.3 (Debian 16.3-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
Connection string used in .NET application:
UserID=knowledgemap;Password=test123;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=knowledgemap;
Driver and version used in .NET app:
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v8.0.4
Relevant portion of pg_hba.conf:
TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     trust

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust


More information needed: 1) Postgres version. 2) The connection string used in the .NET application. 3) The driver(and version) being used in the .NET application.  4) The relevant portion of the pg_hba.conf file. A wild guess is that you have a .pgpass file and the .NET application driver is libpq based and is using that, whereas the JDBC driver is not libpq based and does not use that file.

@AdrianKlaver thanks for the reply. ive added them in the question now.

Something is not adding up the the pg_hba.conf file shows the auth method is trust for everything. In that case a password is not needed. Looks like you are not connecting to what you think you are.

a quick chat with chatgpt says both java driver and .net driver are pure java/C# implementations and not pgpq based

That would be libpq.

sorry that was a typo.. i meant libpq. i stopped the postgres docker container and tried running my .NET app. it fails with the error message Npgsql.PostgresException: '28P01: password authentication failed for user "knowledgemap"'

Then per my previous comment you are not connecting to the Postgres instance you think you are. In other words there is more then one Postgres active in the environment you are working. You will need to figure out how many and which one you need to connect to and with what connection parameters.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There was another postgres instance running in WSL and I was totally unaware of it. apparently java was always going to the WSL one and .NET was always going to the docker one.

It has to do with where you are running the apps. Both are pointing at localhost and port=5432. This means each app is finding the Postgres instance on its version of localhost. From the above it would seem your Java app is running in WSL on the host machine and the .NET app is running in the Docker container.
